# how to android ksoap2 send file

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm sending mail via web service(ksoap2).I sending mail but I can't send file.My tablet in excel file can't send file
That's CODE

```
public void sendData(String _FromMail , String _FromAciklama  , String _To , String _Cc , String _Bcc , String _Konu , String _Icerik , String _EkDosya ) {
       soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE , METHOD_NAME);
       soapObject.addProperty("_FromMail" , _FromMail);
       soapObject.addProperty("_FromAciklama" , _FromAciklama);
       soapObject.addProperty("_To" , _To);
       soapObject.addProperty("_Cc" , _Cc);
       soapObject.addProperty("_Bcc" , _Bcc);
       soapObject.addProperty("_Subject" , _Konu);
       soapObject.addProperty("_Body" , _Icerik);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) , _EkDosya);
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
        DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(source);
        PropertyInfo pro = new PropertyInfo();
        pro.setName("_Attachment");
        pro.setValue(_EkDosya);
        pro.setType(dataHandler.getClass());
        soapObject.addProperty(pro);
       soapSerializationEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
       soapSerializationEnvelope.dotNet = true;
       soapSerializationEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
       httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
       httpTransportSE.debug = true;
       try {
           httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapSerializationEnvelope);
           SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive = (SoapPrimitive) soapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse();
           Log.e("response", soapPrimitive.toString());
           System.out.println(soapPrimitive.toString());
       }catch (XmlPullParserException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
           soapFault.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: Could you explain what is the actual issue you are facing or what's an error you are getting?

Comment: I'm sending mail via web service.A parameter of the web service is sending a file.
It does not see the file I sent as parameter and it is empty.I'm not getting any error

Comment: this file source  `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) , _EkDosya);
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
        DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(source);
        PropertyInfo pro = new PropertyInfo();
        pro.setName("_Attachment");
        pro.setValue(_EkDosya);
        pro.setType(dataHandler.getClass());
        soapObject.addProperty(pro);`